# What are the available options for LayoutAnimation.Types

Tags: react-native, layout-animation

I have a custom layout animation taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/Jpoliachik/0dd83689646d1051b0bc).

```
var CustomLayoutAnimation = {
    duration: 200,
    create: {
      type: LayoutAnimation.Types.linear,
      property: LayoutAnimation.Properties.opacity,
    },
    update: {
      type: LayoutAnimation.Types.curveEaseInEaseOut,
    },
  };
```

When running the code i get the following warning

> Warning: Failed config type: The config `config.update.type` is marked
>   as required in `LayoutAnimation.configureNext`, but its value is
>   `undefined`.

The code has an entry for update.type, yet the warning says it's undefined. I'm guessing that the permitted values have been updated since the gist was written. 
I tried to find out the list of available permitted entries but they are not listed in the [React Native LayoutAnimation documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation.html).

I'd like to know :

- Is the syntax no longer correct?
- Is there a webpage somewhere that details the list of availble Types?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever I run into an issue like this, I go to the source code. [Here's the file for `LayoutAnimation.js` from the `react-native` source code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/1e8f3b11027fe0a7514b4fc97d0798d3c64bc895/Libraries/LayoutAnimation/LayoutAnimation.js). Based on this, I see a `TypesEnum` `const` declaration at line 25 looking like this:

```
const TypesEnum = {
  spring: true,
  linear: true,
  easeInEaseOut: true,
  easeIn: true,
  easeOut: true,
  keyboard: true,
};
```

I suspect that's why you are erring out - `curveEaseInEaseOut` is not a supported type. Choose one from the list above and I think you should be good to go. Hope this helps!